# Can the conditional operator produce a cv-qualified, array, or function type when used on two xvalues of cv-unqualified non-array object type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Given two cv-unqualified non-array object types `T1` and `T2`, can the expression `true ? std::declval<T1>() : std::declval<T2>()` ever have a cv-qualified, array, or function type? I'm fairly sure it can't, but want to make sure that I didn't overlook anything.

---

Motivation: The current proposed resolution of [LWG issue 2465](http://wg21.link/LWG2465) doesn't decay the type of a conditional expression of the form `true? std::declval<D1>() : std::declval<D2>()`, where `D1` and `D2` are produced by `std::decay` (and hence are cv-unqualified non-array object types<sup>*</sup>). This is correct only if decaying the type of the conditional expression has no effect (which is not true if the type is a cv-qualified, array, or function type<sup>**</sup>).

<sub><sup>*</sup> Ignoring the "abnominable function types" case, which is never going to produce a valid expression anyway, and the `void` case, which is a separate problem.</sub>
<sub><sup>**</sup> Per [[expr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#5), expressions never have reference type.</sub>

Comment: Fun fact: 72% [tag:language-lawyer] question titles require at least three passes to be parsed.

Comment: I would have expected that http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/343461d1d3480549 yielded `const A` by calling the conversion function and taking the union-cv-qualification of both sides, but apparently it copies the conversion-function result into a new `A` object. Or it strips away the `const` which I don't think it does, since it would be unsafe.

Comment: Verified: It copies the return value into a new temporary: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7472669e49a8a790

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove this using [[expr.cond]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond):

> 2. If either the second or the third operand has type `void`, [...]

The first sub-bullet talks about *throw-expression*s as operands, the second one gives result type `void`.

> 3. Otherwise, if the second and third operand are glvalue bit-fields of the same value category and of types *cv1*
>      `T` and *cv2* `T`, respectively, the operands are considered to be of type *cv* `T` for the remainder of this section,
>      where *cv* is the union of *cv1* and *cv2*.

The union of empty sets is empty, so nothing to worry about here.

> 4. Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class
>      type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an
>      attempt is made to form an implicit conversion sequence (13.3.3.1) from each of those operands to the type
>      of the other.

Let's analyze each following case:

> - (4.1) If `E2` is an lvalue, **the target type is “lvalue reference to `T2`”**, [..].
> - (4.2) If `E2` is an xvalue, **the target type is “rvalue reference to `T2`”**,  [..].

Expression is thus of type `T2`, cv-unqualified by assumption.

> - (4.3) If `E2` is a prvalue or if neither of the conversion sequences above can be formed and at least one of the operands has (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - if `T1` and `T2` are the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification), or one is a base class of the other, and `T2` is at least as cv-qualified as `T1`, **the target type is `T2`**,
>   - otherwise, the target type is the type that `E2` would have after applying the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions.

In the first case, the target type is cv-unqualified by assumption.

Finally, l-t-r conversions do not add cv-qualification ([[conv.lval]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#1)). And *-to-pointer conversions cannot do that, either; in fact, what they yield after an application is a prvalue of pointer (that is, non-array, non-class) type, which as per [[expr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#6) is never cv-qualified. Since `E2` is of type `T2`, the target type is cv-unqualified in this case, too.

Comment: ...and the [expr.cond]/6 overload resolution never results in added cv-qualification either (and in any event only yields scalar types, so any hypothetical cv-qualification is immediately stripped by l-t-r in [expr.cond]/7).